# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to get the `Score_Waarde` value from my database using the following code :

```
critid = critid_arr[teller2].ToString();

int scorehulp = 0;
string userid = Session["userid"].ToString();

SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Score_Waarde FROM Score WHERE Crit_ID = '" + critid + "' AND User_ID = '" + userid + "' ", con);
scorehulp = (int)cmd3.ExecuteScalar();
```

When I try to run this I get the following error: **Specified cast is not valid**.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error because `critid` and `userid` are giving the correct values.

Comment: With the debugger attached, what value *is* returned? If it isn't of type `System.Int32` then that will die horribly. (E.g. if it returned a `long` or `byte` it wouldn't work.) Best way to find/fix is to test check the assumptions; and using a debugger here will skip 20 steps :-)

Comment: You could try [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) on the String representation of the return value. But be careful with `Null` values. `Int32.Parse(cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString())`

Comment: You should check that the value returned is not `DBNull`.

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to declare scorehulp as a nullable value type (such as `int?`) in case the person's score is not found.

Comment: @Tim: No; that's not the way to do it.

Comment: I used a debugger to find out if it is actually giving some values to critid and userid. And it does give the correct values. The data I want to get is stored as a nchar(10)  <- Score_Waarde. But this has never given me problems before ?

Comment: **Why do you have a number in a string field**?

Comment: @Slaks: coming back to my Int32.Parse-approach ;) I was afraid of this.

Comment: Good question.. I think it was giving errors elsewhere when i used an int field and quickly swapped it to a text field, pretty dumb AND cheap I know. Changed it to : scorehulp = Int32.Parse(cmd3.ExecuteScalar().ToString());  and it works !  Learned my lesson now never to work like this egain :) numbers /= string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your SQL is probably giving back a different numeric type, such as `long` or `decimal`, or, apparently, `string`.

Call `Convert.ToInt32`, which doesn't have the [limitations of an unboxing cast](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I was originally getting this error (my C# code

```
someobject.TotalItemCount = (Int32)dbManager.GetParameterValue("TotalRows"))
```

where `TotalItemCount` was of `int` type, even though the SP was fine & was giving proper result. I got rid of this just by fixing the SP by adding the following code

```
Set @TotalRows =  @@rowcount.
```